# Saving updated array in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Ive seen some other questions, but none of them seem to help.

Basically here is my controller:

```
  def append
  y = Post.find(params[:id])
  y.tags_will_change!
  y.tags.push(params[:x].to_i)
  y.save!
  Post.find(params[:id]).tags
redirect_to root_path
    end
```

and I get this error, PG::InvalidTextRepresentation at /posts/22/append
ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information.

Request parameters
    {"x"=>"9", "controller"=>"posts", "action"=>"append", "id"=>"22"}

Note: tags is defined as an integer type array => true (i.e. an integer array)

Post model migration:

```
class AddTagsToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :tags, :integer, array: true, default: []
  end
end
```

from schema.rb :

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|

t.integer  "tags",          default: [],              array: true
```

Ive checked the other answers on here, but none seemed to help.

Comment: can you post your `params` data

Comment: Show your Post model migration..

Comment: and are you getting On rails console can you try `p = Post.first` `p.tags.class` `p.tags.push(2)`

Comment: show the full file from your schema.rb file for the Post model.